# What's the effect of blowing candles?

Tags: dishonored

I know it doesn't change anything about visibility, since [Dishonored doesn't make any use of lights and shadows](http://www.eurogamer.net/articles/2012-09-29-why-dishonored-ditched-its-thief-shadow-stealth-mechanic).  So does it change anything wheter I blow the candles or not ?

[image]

Comment: I blow them because i feel cool. You stealth your way all around the enemies and kill the target in a fashionable way. Then you can get out feeling cool saying "Lights out now" and blow away the candles. They should implement this...

Comment: "*Dishonored doesn't make any use of lights and shadows.*" Actually, [Dishonored does](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/98024/4797).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you know they emit light and you are easier seen in light. So by blowing the candles, it will get darker and it will be easier to hide.

I do not think the candle above has any purpose since it is in a well lit area.

Comment: As written in [the link I gave in the original question](http://www.eurogamer.net/articles/2012-09-29-why-dishonored-ditched-its-thief-shadow-stealth-mechanic), the light has no influence on the infiltration aspect of this game.

Comment: There is load screen help text that says that shadows *do* conceal you, but only at a distance. Anecdotal evidence during my various playthroughs appears to confirm this.

Comment: yes enemys have harder to see you on distance if you are in the dark